# Who can see a new name of the planet?

Tags: no-mans-sky

I've discovered a planet and renamed it to "New name". Will any person who discovers that planet see this "New name"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Yes**, if said player is on the same platform as you are (I assume PS4 since PC version is not released as of the time of this answer).

PC players won't see that planet name this way, because according to Sean Murray in a [Reddit AMA](https://np.reddit.com/r/IAmA/comments/4wsra2/i_quit_my_job_at_ea_where_i_worked_on_burnout/d69przk), the universes from each platform are in separate servers.